# window.screenX / screenY are not being update on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, window, screen

I've created this small test page, that prints the window.screenX and screenY in a loop, it fails to update the values on chrome

> Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit) on mac

(works fine on Safari and FF):

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const wrapperClick = document.getElementById('wrapperClick');

document.body.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
  wrapperClick.innerText = `${ window.screenX }, ${ window.screenY }, ${ window.innerWidth } × ${ window.innerHeight }`;
});

function refreshLoop() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    wrapper.innerText = `${ window.screenX }, ${ window.screenY }, ${ window.innerWidth } × ${ window.innerHeight }, ${ Math.random().toFixed(2) }`;
    
    refreshLoop();
  });
}

refreshLoop();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper,
#wrapperClick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#wrapperClick {
  top: 52px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<div id="wrapperClick"></div>
```

Is that a chrome bug?

Answer (score 1):

When testing it on Chrome `67.0.3396.62` on Mac, the values are updating correctly but only once you stop resizing/moving the window, which is the current behaviour right now.

There's an issue that has been sitting around since the beginning of 2014 reporting that and requesting a change:

[**screenX and screenY parameters don't update until you pause dragging**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=320490)

> **What steps will reproduce the problem?**
>
> 1. Launch sample app (attached).
> 2. Drag it around.
>
> Notice that the `screenX` and `screenY` only update after you stop moving the mouse. This is inconsistent with the behaviour of the `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` which update during resizing.
>
> A much more useful behaviour would be if the `screenX` and `screenY` parameters updated during a drag, not just at the end of it.

Comment: Why do you need that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm working on a POS, detecting an Android webView position, using JS only. when I click inside the webView I can get the X/Y of the screen and the X/Y relative to the webView (clientX/Y). I can then calculate the position of the webView. I'm trying to calculate the same value when the native app is scrolled.

Comment: I would just try to implement it with the current behaviour. The users probably just care about whether the application looks right once they stop resizing/moving it. Whatever workaround you can find, it's probably not worth the effort.